# Linux kernel compilation taking over 4 GB of temporary disk space

Tags: linux-kernel

I am trying to compile linux kernel 2.6 and am shocked to see it is taking over 4 Gigs of disk space. It is also taking around 80 minutes to compile. Is it normal ? Or am I doing something wrong ?

> make menuconfig
>
> make

These are the commands I am executing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it needs to turn the source in a bunch of object files and link them afterwards. And there are probably also a lot of other files that have to do with it.

Yes, it's normal for the Linux Kernel compilation to take a while. It depends on your computer and how you configured `/etc/make.conf` in terms of optimization and parallel compilation...

Comment: thats too bad for me .. i am building it on a virtual machine that has only 4.5 GB free space and am getting out of space :(